# Equivalence class of double coset

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $A$, $B$ subgroups of G.  If $x$, $y$ $\in$ $G$ define the relation $\sim$ as follows: $x \sim y$ if $y = axb$, for some $a \in A, b \in B$.  Prove that:

a) The relation $\sim$ is an equivalence relation in $G$.

b) The equivalence class of $x$ is $[x] = AxB = \{axb | a \in A, b \in B\}$.

I have already proved part a, so I know that this is an equivalence relation.  I need to work on part b.  This could be much simpler than I think it is, I do have a history of this.  Any help, in terms of hints or the answer with explanations, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So what's exactly is your question? If you have proven part (a), part (b) seems just the definition of equivalence class, that is: the elements which are in relation with x...

Comment: Well that is what I would think.  Is it simply the definition of equivalence classes or is there something to prove here?  I've never been with the rigor of proof so I feel like saying that it being the definition of equivalence classes is too straight forward.

Comment: You could prove two inclusions: [x] is in the right hand side and vice versa. If you write it down (or take a look at the answer bellow) you will see that the answer is a one-liner :)

Comment: I appreciate the help.  Turns out this was much simpler than I assumed.

Answer (score 1):

By definition $[x]:=\left\{y\in G\mid y=axb \mbox{ for }a\in A, b\in B\right\}$. So now the two inclusions follows immediately.